# JNA Struct and Pointer mapping

Tags: java, jna

How does one map the function below to java?

**VOID WriteToStruct(BOOL *Status, STRUCT_MSG RecBuff)**

What this function does: 
1) Populates the struct RecBuff
2) Updates status

How do I map to a boolean pointer in Java and access the struct data updated by the function?

Answer (score 7):

I was searching for another issue concerning JNA and structs, and Google redirected me here.  I hope this helps.

From [JNA API](https://jna.dev.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html#byvalue)

> To pass a structure by value, first
>   define the structure, then define an
>   empty class from that which implements
>   Structure.ByValue. Use the ByValue
>   class as the argument or return type.
>
> ```
> // Original C code
> typedef struct _Point {
>   int x, y;
> } Point;
>
> Point translate(Point pt, int dx, int dy);
>
> // Equivalent JNA mapping
> class Point extends Structure {
>     public static class ByValue extends Point implements Structure.ByValue { }
>     public int x, y;
> }
> Point.ByValue translate(Point.ByValue pt, int x, int y);
> ...
> Point.ByValue pt = new Point.ByValue();
> Point result = translate(pt, 100, 100);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ByReference class to pass values by reference.  Presuming BOOL is an int you can use IntegerByReference.